# Link de archivos static en Python y Flask con url_for

Tags: html, python, flask

Se que tal vez se trata de un error de novato, pero ya he intentando de todo.

El problema es que poseo un proyecto en Python en la cual tengo las carpetas de static(dentro de esta las carpetas css y js) y templates(donde se encuentra mi html).

Cuando intento llamas los archivos css y js en el codigo del html no me los reconoce:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">`

Tal vez me estoy equivocando en algo, pero he buscado y esas deberia ser la manera correcta de hacer referencia a cualquier archivo...

[image: Por si es importante adjunto la estructura de los archivos]

Comment: Prueba a usar Ctrl+F5. Así fuerzas a refrescar la página y actualizar la caché.

Answer (score 0):

la funcion url_for En flask se usa para regresar a una ruta y no depender del nombre de la ruta sino de la funcion adentro.

Por ejemplo digamos que tienes una pagina de un restaurante y la ruta del menu se llama "comidas"
`tusitio.com/comidas`

En tu aplicacion de flask se miraria asi:

```
@app.route('/comidas', methods=["GET", "POST"])

def menu():
    #Codigo
    return(render_template(plantilla.html))
```

y si tuvieras un boton al menu desde otra pagina tienes dos opciones:
hacer uso del nombre de la ruta

`return redirect"/comidas"`

Lo cual si tuvieras un cambio en el nombre de la ruta (/comidas) siempre en donde mandes a redirigir a esa ruta tendrias que modificar el redirect

o podrias hacerlo con el nombre de la funcion en la ruta(menu)

`return redirect (url_for('menu') #Menu es el nombre de la funcion mas no de la ruta`

Donde dificilmente tendrias que verte forzado a cambiar el nombre de la funcion y siempre mantendriael mismo.

Ahora el problema que tienes es que estas intentando llamar a un archivo css y dandole como ruta del archivo una ruta de tu aplicacion. La manera de enlazar un archivo css es
`<link rel='stylesheet' href='archivo.css'>`  En tu caso seria:

`<link rel='stylesheet' href='../static/css/style.css'>`

Y para llamar a un archivo javascript (supongamos que tienes el arhcivo script.js) donde termina la etiqueta body (`</body>`) pon `<script src=./static/js/script.js> </script>`